# php объединить два многомерных массива

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте, есть два однотипных многомерных массива, вот пример

```
$first_arr =[
'date1' => ['type_1' => 'counts'],
'date2' => ['type_1' => 'counts'],
'date3' => ['type_1' => 'counts']
];

$second_arr =[
'date1' => ['type_2' => 'counts'],
'date2' => ['type_2' => 'counts'],
'date3' => ['type_2' => 'counts']
];
```

Необходимо объединить их так, что бы получился следующий массив:

```
$result_arr =[
'date1' => ['type_1' => 'counts', 'type_2' => 'counts'],
'date2' => ['type_1' => 'counts', 'type_2' => 'counts'],
'date3' => ['type_1' => 'counts', 'type_2' => 'counts']
];
```

Казалось бы - основа основ, но не получается сделать так, как нужно. Делаю так:

```
foreach ($first_arr as $key => $value){
            $data[$key] = ['type_1' => $value['counts']];
}

foreach ($second_arr as $key => $value) {

        array_push($data[$key], $value['counts']);
}
```

Результат :

```
$result_arr =[
'date1' => ['type_1' => 'counts', 0 => 'counts'],
'date2' => ['type_1' => 'counts', 1 => 'counts'],
'date3' => ['type_1' => 'counts', 2' => 'counts']
];
```

Возможно, можно обойтись более элегантным решением?

Comment: количество значений и ключи массивов совпадают?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так не пойдёт?

```
foreach ($second_arr as $key => $value) {

        $data[$key] += ['type_2' => $value['counts']];
}
```

А ещё можно сделать вот так:

```
foreach ($first_arr as $key => $value){
    $data[$key] = $value;
}

foreach ($second_arr as $key => $value){
    $data[$key] += $value;
}
```

Ведь значением `$value` является вложенный массив.

Comment: идеально, спасибо

Comment: Только в php < 5.4 нужно заменить `[]` после `+=` на `array()`

Answer (score 1):

Еще более элегантное решение, использовать функцию 
[array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Пример

```
$first_arr =[
    'date1' => ['type_1' => 'counts'],
    'date2' => ['type_1' => 'counts'],
    'date3' => ['type_1' => 'counts']
];

$second_arr =[
    'date1' => ['type_2' => 'counts'],
    'date2' => ['type_2' => 'counts'],
    'date3' => ['type_2' => 'counts'],
    'date4' => ['type_2' => 'counts']
];

$res_array = array_merge_recursive($first_arr, $second_arr);

print_r($res_array);
```

вернет вам

```
Array
(
    [date1] => Array
        (
            [type_1] => counts
            [type_2] => counts
        )

    [date2] => Array
        (
            [type_1] => counts
            [type_2] => counts
        )

    [date3] => Array
        (
            [type_1] => counts
            [type_2] => counts
        )

    [date4] => Array
        (
            [type_2] => counts
        )

)
```

Насколько я понял вопрос, именно это и было нужно. При этом, сработает даже если количество элементов в массивах разное.